# How to query rows in between two datetime columns?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to query rows in between two datetime columns?

**My Example Table:**

```
 message     |      startdatetime           |      enddatetime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hi           |   2013-04-09 10:00:00       |    2013-04-09 10:30:00

Good morning |   2013-04-09 10:40:00       |    2013-04-09 10:50:00
```

**My query:**

fromDateTime="2013-04-09 10:00:00 ";
toDateTime="2013-04-09 10:50:00 ";

```
c1 = myDB.rawQuery("select * from masterdatatable where number=? and startdatetime >= datetime(?) and enddatetime <= datetime(?) order by enddatetime, new String[]{imei,fromDateTime,toDateTime});
```

here if pass `fromDateTime="2013-04-09 10:00:00 " and  toDateTime="2013-04-09 10:50:00 "` this query returns above two records properly.

But If i pass `fromDateTime="2013-04-09 10:05:00 "; toDateTime="2013-04-09 10:20:00 "`, this query returns empty cursor. Actually I expect this query to return first row . How to achieve this?

Comment: is it any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by following method,

```
Cursor c0 = myDB.rawQuery("select startdatetime from masterdatatable where datetime(?) >= startdatetime and  datetime(?) <= enddatetime order by startdatetime asc limit 1", new String[]{fromDateTime,fromDateTime});

String fromDate1=fromDateTime;
if(c0.moveToFirst())
{
    fromDate1 = c0.getString(0);
}

Log.i("date", "fromDate1->"+fromDate1);

Cursor c01 = myDB.rawQuery("select startdatetime from masterdatatable where datetime(?) >= startdatetime and  datetime(?) <= enddatetime order by startdatetime desc limit 1", new String[]{toDateTime,toDateTime});
String fromDate2=toDateTime;
if(c01.moveToFirst())
{
    fromDate2 = c01.getString(0);
}

Log.i("date", "fromDate2->"+fromDate2);

c1 = myDB.rawQuery("select * from masterdatatable where startdatetime  between datetime(?) and datetime(?)  order by enddatetime, new String[]{fromDate1,fromDate2});
```

Answer (score 0):

it wont return the first row because of your condition.. the endTime of the first row doesn't

```
 2013-04-09 10:30:00 doesn't
```

smaller than

```
 toDateTime="2013-04-09 10:20:00
```

and because of that you're not getting the first row..

**UPDATE:**
If you still want to return the first row, you can create a new query
that will check if the startDate is between the given inputs..

Answer (score 0):

Try using following SQL query

```
select * from masterdatatable 
where number=? 
and fromdate between startdatetime and enddatetime 
and todate between startdatetime and enddatetime
order by enddatetime
```

Comment: @Avi it won't work because his condition was from 
'10:05:00" to '10:20:00'

look at the table data he gave.. no row answer this condition!

Comment: @Elior ..Yes true his inputs are for sure not satisfying given where caluse condition .. I was trying to give alternate solution.